# How to know if my data has been scaled by StandardScaler?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, scaling

"I have scaled my dataset by using Standard Scaler , Now how to know it has been scaled, I am sure it has been scaled but how to see it"

Comment: just check the `mean` and `std` of each feature of your dataset.. the mean = 0 and std = 1

Comment: Thank you @coder

Answer (score 0):

As @Coderji said you can always find out the mean and standard deviation, which should be equal to 0 and 1 respectively.
However, there is another method to visualize it.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

I am using iris dataset for this example.

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X)
x = sc.transform(X)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(x[:,1])
```

[See this Output for sepel length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPo75.png)

Similarly you can see for all variables or a simple pairplot will do the job.
This gives an idea that the data is standardised visually.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems helpful.